# My javascript code does not work when I add media query?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Never ran into this problem before. Basically I added a class list toggle on my header via Javascript, and it normally works fine, but when I add media queries that have nothing to do with the header, it stops working.  If you need any more info let me know. Any ideas? I'm lost

EDIT: Added additional HTML Code

Here's all my code

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  let header = document.querySelector('.page-header');
  header.classList.toggle('sticky', window.scrollY > 30);
})
```

```css
  .page-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  transition: .7s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.page-header.sticky {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .7s;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px lightgray;
}

.portfolio-images {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.portfolio-images img {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.portfolio-images img:hover {
  filter: brightness(.4);
  transition: .4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* media queries */

@media all and (max-width: 1275px) {
  .portfolio-images {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .portfolio-images img {
    width: 40vw;
    height: auto;
  }
  @media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .portfolio-images {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .portfolio-images img {
      width: 90vw;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h1 id="logo">ParallaxStudios</h1>
  <div class="navigation-container">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="navigation-item">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a class="navigation-item">Socials</a></li>
      <li><a class="navigation-item">Staff</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="rightside-navigation">
    <h3 id="contact">Contact</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="portfolio-container">
  <h1>Current Projects</h1>
  <div class="portfolio-images">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/420">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are no elements in the provided HTML with a class of "page-header".

Comment: Please provide a working [mcve]. We can’t help if we cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: I don't think the Javascript "stopped working". I'm 100% certain you still get that sticky class toggled properly. It might not do what you expect though, especially if your sticky class is defined below your media queries in your CSS.

Comment: You have a  typo - missing losing brace at end of a media query so not all the CSS is being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

You literally have one missing `}` in the end the of one of the Media Queries here:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1275px) {
    .portfolio-images {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
    .portfolio-images img {
      width: 40vw;
      height: auto;
  }
} //this one was missing.
  
  @media all and (max-width: 500px) {
    .portfolio-images {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
    .portfolio-images img {
      width: 90vw;
      height: auto;
    }
  }
```

Comment: From my experience when a curly bracket is missing usually everything stops working, I had that problem before too, but VSCode helped me a lot about with missing stuff, because it give out a lot error messages, like the one I just found, I wouldn't have found even this one if I didn't use VSCode probably lol.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It cannot, but it can very well ruin any CSS code after that. And if that CSS contains the definition for `.sticky`it can make you think your JS is broken.

Comment: That makes perfect sense tbh.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It only doesn't work now when i minimize the window

Comment: Can you elaborate on what doesn't work when you minimize the window?